# django equivalent of app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')) to serve static files

Tags: django

I'm very new to django, and am simply trying to serve a folder of static html,css, and js files for development.  In Node, I'd use `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))` - is there a simple equivalent to this in django?  I'm not looking to use any django templates if possible.  Perhaps a way to serve a directory for a route in urls.py?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`serve()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static-file-development-view) view from the `staticfiles` app.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not looking to use any django templates if possible. Perhaps a way
>   to serve a directory for a route in urls.py?

Sure, how about this:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urls = [ .... ] # your normal urls

urls += static('/url-prefix', document_root='/file/system/path/to/public')
```